# How do I raise my effective health in robocraft?

Tags: robocraft

I have been playing and in t3 there are a lot of enemies that have one shot weapons. I was wondering how to get more HP to tank at least one shot, and maybe have a friend heal me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To raise your health([armor](http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Armor)) and sustain more damage, you simply have to buy and upgrade the [cubes](http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Cube) your tank is made of.

Mainly your tank will consist of [chassis cubes](http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Chassis_cubes), where white cubes are the lowest tier, and will sustain the least damage (50hp). You can buy upgraded cubes all the way up to tier 10, which sustains 933 damage per cube.
All the cubes you build your tank with, have a set armor rating. Even your guns and wheels. And the higher tier, the higher armor. In higher tiers (from T2 and up) you can also buy [electroplates](http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Electroplates), which are kind of a regerative shield, which recharges after you get hit, but gets destroyed once it sustains a set amount of damage. These shields are more costly, but can sustain much more damage than normal cubes (up to 34 000 damage for T10).